# Show screen on external display

Tags: ios5, uistoryboard

I look at some examples at Github, but all of them were without storyboard usage.

I tried to use that code in my app, but all I see on external device in simulator is black screen.

Code I have now:

```
if([[UIScreen screens]count] > 1) {

    CGSize maxSize;
    UIScreenMode *maxScreenMode;

    for(int i = 0; i < [[[[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1] availableModes]count]; i++)
    {
        UIScreenMode *current = [[[[UIScreen screens]objectAtIndex:1]availableModes]objectAtIndex:i];
        if(current.size.width > maxSize.width)
        {
            maxSize = current.size;
            maxScreenMode = current;
        }
    }
    UIScreen *externalScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
    externalScreen.currentMode = maxScreenMode;
    [self myScreenInit:externalScreen];
}

- (void) screenDidConnect:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self myScreenInit:[notification object]];
}


- (void) myScreenInit:(UIScreen *)connectedScreen {
    CGRect frame = connectedScreen.bounds;
    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [window setScreen:connectedScreen];
    window.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see more than a black screen you'll need to put in some content. One option would be to add something like this:

```
UIView *myCustomUIView = [[MyCustomUIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[window addSubview:myCustomUIView];
```

Then draw stuff in the view's drawRect:(CGRect) method.

Hope this helps.